# Iterator cannot iterative again

Tags: java, iterator

Here is my Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    map.put("_name", "name");  
    map.put("_age", "age");  
    Set<String> set = map.keySet();  
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();  
    // the first iteration  
    StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer();  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
        str1.append(iterator.next() + ",");  
    }  
    String str1To = str1.substring(0, str1.lastIndexOf(",")).toString();  
    System.out.println(str1To);  
    // the second iteration  
    StringBuffer str2 = new StringBuffer();  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
        str2.append(iterator.next() + ",");  
    }  
    String str2To = str2.substring(0, str2.lastIndexOf(",")).toString();// ?????  
    System.out.println(str2To);  
}
```

My question is,why doesn't the second loop iterate? Does the first iteration already takes the `iterator` to the end? Is this what affects the second iteration?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `while` loop would move iterate till the `iterator` reaches the end of the list. At that moment the `iterator` in itself is pointing to the end of the `list`, in your case the `map.keySet()`. And that is the reason why your next `while` loop fails because the call to the `iterator.hasNext()` returns `false`.

A better way would be to use the [`Enhanced For Loop`](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with), something like this instead of your `while` loops:

```
for(String key: map.keySet()){
    //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator's are for one time use only. So ask for iterator again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `set.iterator()` each time you want to iterate through a collection. I suggest that you use a different variable for each iteration as well.